# fetch выводит в коносль ошибки не смотря на .catch

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch

Здравтвуйте,

Обработка неудавшихся запросов - совершенно не проблема

У меня большая проблема, что fetch выводит в консоль ошибки.. И я прям ничего не могу с этим поделать. если запрос не 200 - консоль краснеет, и они никак не ловятся.. Есть ли простой способ заткнуть fetch?

**Собственно код:**

```js
fetch(url)
    .then(resp => {
        if (!resp.ok) {
            throw Error(`is not ok`);
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.warn(err)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.warn(err)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.warn(err)
    });
```

**Задача сделать консоль не крассной:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P. S. Fetch даже нельзя завернуть в try catch, в виду его асинхронности

P. S. S. Начинаю ненавидеть fetch

Comment: _Есть ли простой способ заткнуть fetch?_ и даже непростого нет

Comment: КМК, это не fetch, а сам браузер. И настраивается это в шестерёнке справа

Comment: Серьезно? Сам браузер? В смысле в коде никак не реализовать?

Comment: Да, это браузер видит, что запрос был ошибочный и показывает вам для вашего удобства ошибку в консоль. В коде вы это никак не исправите, разве что **НИКОГДА** не будете провоцировать ошибки сервера)

Comment: Жесть, я понял. Спасибо конечно.. Как мне теперь вопрос закрыть? Никто не написал в ответы, только в комментарии

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам отвечу иначе не могу закрыть топик. Спасибо комментаторам.

Если http(s) запрос был не удачным, то хром будет выводить ошибку, будь то `fetch` или `XMLHttpRequest`, или просто в теге `img` будет неправильно указан `src` на картинку..

Все http(s) ошибки будут попадать в раздел "network" в консоли, которые можно отключить только на уровне браузера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]